# How can I print a JavaScript loop to an element by ID?

Tags: javascript

The same output I get in a console.log is not posting to the HTML div and I cannot figure out why.

I am expecting this array to print:

```
["Thief", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"]
```

```js
const myLibrary = ["Thief", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"];

function Book() {
  // the constructor
}

var bookLength = myLibrary.length;


function addBookToLibrary() {
  for (var b = 0; b < bookLength; b++)
    console.log(myLibrary[b]);
    
  return myLibrary[b];
}

var labels = document.getElementById("myBooks").innerHTML;
labels = addBookToLibrary();
```

```html
<p>My list should be below</p>
<p id="myBooks"></p>

<!-- script src="script.js"></script -->
```

Comment: "*I am expecting this array to print const myLibrary*" - you declare the `labels` variable, and then *immediately* overwrite it with the result of the function, but nowhere do you try to "print const myLibrary" anywhere except to the console. Incidentally, could you please edit your posted code to remove the typo (unless you really meant to wrap your code with "typ" and "e here," which seems very unlikely.

Comment: The variable `labels` is a string, not a reference. You’ve copied the `innerHTML` to the variable, and then immediately overwritten it with the result of `addBookToLibrary()`. You should assign it directly: `….innerHTML = addBookToLibrary();` .

Comment: Code is fixed. i need myLibrary[b] to print for sure and the results be added to a variable maybe. labels is undefined and I dont get why yet

Comment: No, it isn't; `typconst` remains a typo, which breaks your code. Where is `labels` undefined?

Comment: Reassigning your `labels` variable doesn't update the `innerHTML` you got it from. The variable is a copy of the innerHTML value, not a pointer to it. Another note--your `for` loop advances your `b` counter to the length of the array and then you return `myLibrary[b]`. My guess is that's not what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues in play:

**1. Your `labels` variable is a copy of innerHTML's value, not a reference to it.**

Your `labels` variable is not a reference to the source element's `innerHTML`. It is a copy of its value at the time you assigned it. So changing the value of `labels` does not affect the source element in any way whatsoever.

If you want to update the element's innerHTML you must assign it directly. (There are other ways to do this, but for the purposes of this question I'm focusing on what OP is trying to do.)

```js
const myLibrary = ["Thief", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"];

document.querySelector('#myBooks').innerHTML = myLibrary.join('<br/>');
```

```html
<p>My list should be below</p>
<p id="myBooks"></p>
```

---

**2. You loop over the array to log them, then return `undefined`.**

The reason your `console.log(labels);` call emits `undefined` is because your `for` loop advances `b` until it's the length of the array, and then you return `myLibrary[b]`.

Javascript arrays are zero-indexed, meaning the first item is `n[0]` and the last item is at `n[length - 1]`.

Because your `b` variable is equal to `myLibrary.length` when your for loop exits, `myLibrary[b]` is `undefined`, so that's what you see in the log.

```js
const myLibrary = ["Thief", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"];

function addBook() {
  for(var b = 0; b < myLibrary.length; b++) {
  }
  console.log(b); // 4
  return myLibrary[b]; // myLibrary[4] === undefined;
}

addBook();
```

Comment: Thanks your first comment set me on the path to answer

Comment: @JermainSingleton Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if one best answers your question.

Comment: @ray - A refreshing change to see an answer like this. Thanks for helping to keep SO worth visiting. :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const myLibrary = ["Theif", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"];

function Book() {
  // the constructor
}

var bookLength = myLibrary.length;
var outer = "";

var labels = document.getElementById("myBooks")
function addBookToLibrary() {
  for (var b = 0; b < bookLength; b++){
    labels.innerHTML += myLibrary[b] + "<br>"
    outer += myLibrary[b] + '\n'
    console.log(myLibrary[b]);
   } 
  return outer;
  
}


labels = addBookToLibrary();

console.log(labels);
```

```html
<p>My list should be below</p>
<p id="myBooks"></p>

<!-- script src="script.js"></script -->
```

Comment: Thanks I did something similar in the end. I wanted the line break to be smoother though

Comment: interesting.  what do you mean by ...wanted the line break smoother?

Comment: go to the next line

Answer (score -2):

```js
const myLibrary = ["Theif", "The Lion", "Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"];

function Book(){
    // the constructor
}

function addBookToLibrary(myLibrary) {
    var result = "";
    for (var library in myLibrary){
        console.log(myLibrary[library]);
        result += myLibrary[library] + "<br>";
    }
    return result
}


document.getElementById("myBooks").innerHTML = addBookToLibrary(myLibrary);
```

The result I came to. I am confused why the return result worked but remembered i needed it from past lessons, i googled the

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve op's problem and I think you didn't finish a sentence in your answer, you can still edit your answer.